# Mvc login with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In my solution folder there are two projects

- Myproject.API
- Myproject.Web

API will server all the request to My Mvc web or android or IOS client.

Now Here I'm confused, Where should I Implement Authentication process.

- At API or
- At API and MVC both

As MVC identity uses Cookie based authentication where as API used token based.

Now What I want In Web Project, If any user try to open a page which is only for `Authorize` user, and if he is not logged in then he should be redirect to Login page, And It is possible when I'll MVC Identity.

If I'll Implement At API then How I'll manage cookies at Web Project.

and How I'll Send that token in every request from WEB to API

Comment: @TinMan7757 security doesnt work that way in asp.net....

Comment: @amit you could use Owin to secure both MVC and the API  and they both need to be secured , take a look at this http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: @Thorarins: I have seen that tutorial , That is token based. And AngularJs project can easily uses token based authentication But How I'll handle my action at web using token authentication .

Comment: you have to combine cookie and token, cookie for mvc and token for the api calls

Comment: @Thorarins: Thank you, But That's what I'm looking for. Need some Idea how to combine them

Comment: It appears to me that you are in need of a centralized authentication and authorization mechanism. The right thing to do is to implement an external Auth Server that will manage authentication for every client. Take a look at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/).

Comment: I agree with @FedericoDipuma ... that is how I implemented it and I was in same exact situation. IdentityServer is fantastic !